# What does the 2nd dimension (index 1) of each contour represent in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

In the following code:

```
contours, h = cv2.findContours(
    img_bin, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE
)
print(contours[0].shape)
```

The output is:

```
(299, 1, 2)
```

What does the 2nd value (index 1 of the contour) represent? Does it always equal 1?

Comment: That's just how the automatic mapping of C++ types to Python works in OpenCV. Contour is a vector of points in C++ -> each entry the vector is represented by a row, each entry consists of 1 point represented by column, and each point has 2 values, represented by the 3rd numpy array dimension.

Comment: a `cv::Mat` has a width and height and a depth (number of channels). that is mapped to a numpy array of shape `(H, W, C)`. by OpenCV convention, a list of points is a column vector Mat of n-channel elements. hence the shape becomes `(N, 1, 2)` -- I'm following the question and will post this as an answer if I have to

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I guess this should be the answer. If you post it I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV maps between numpy arrays and `cv::Mat`, which is used internally and in the C++ bindings.

A `cv::Mat` has a width and height and a number of channels.

That shape is mapped to a numpy array of shape `(H, W, C)`, in both directions. If OpenCV seems fussy about some numpy array you give it, it helps to reshape/transpose the data into that specific shape.

By OpenCV convention, any **list of points** is commonly represented as a **column vector** cv::Mat of **C-channel elements** (the points). Hence the shape becomes `(N, 1, 2)`

When your numpy array has the shape `(N, 2)`, the Python bindings of OpenCV may interpret that as a N-by-2, single-channel Mat. Most/all OpenCV APIs accept this format implicitly as an alternative to the column vector format.

The `contours` *list* (or tuple) from `findContours` contains a bunch of numpy arrays. Each contour will always have the shape `(N, 1, 2)` for however many points are in that specific contour.

You can call the **`.squeeze(axis=1)`** method to collapse that extra dimension.